# When is planned the next version of light-rest-4j to be released?

Tags: rest, light-4j

When is planned the next version of light-rest-4j to be released?
Is there any list of known issues in the current version?

Answer (score 0):

As a lot of customers are using light-rest-4j, we are trying our best to ensure backward compitability. Normally, we have a release scheduled between 4 to 6 weeks for new features and defect fixes. You can find release notes at https://github.com/networknt/light-rest-4j/releases and all releases are posted in our sub-reddit at https://www.reddit.com/r/lightapi